# elasticsearch mapping for timeseries

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-mapping, elasticsearch-template

We are planning to use elasticsearch as timeseries database for our metric store. After going through the following blog (https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-as-a-time-series-data-store) on elasticsearch as timeseries database, i came up with following Mapping

```
{
"template": "metricsets-*",
"version": 50001,
"settings": {
    "index.refresh_interval": "5s"
},
"mappings": {
    "_default_": {
        "_all": { "enabled": false },
        "_source": { "enabled": false },
        "dynamic_templates": [
            { "string_fields": { "match": "*", "match_mapping_type": "string", "mapping": { "type": "keyword" } } },
            { "tags": { "match_mapping_type": "string", "path_match": "tag.*", "mapping": { "type": "keyword" } } }, 
            { "metrics_object": { "match_mapping_type": "object", "mapping": { "type": "object", "index": false } } },
            { "metrics_long": { "match_mapping_type": "long", "mapping": { "type": "float", "index": false } } },
            { "metrics_double": { "match_mapping_type": "double", "mapping": { "type": "float", "index": false } } },
            { "metrics_boolean": { "match_mapping_type": "boolean", "mapping": { "type": "boolean", "index": false } } }
        ],
        "properties": {
            "@timestamp": { "type": "date" },
            "@version": { "type": "keyword"}
        }
    }
  }
}
```

we use metricbeat for metrics collection and logstash as ingestor. We are using elasticsearch 5.x version.

metricbeat --> logstash --> elasticsearch --> grafana/kibana.

Is my template rightly optimized for metric store? Am i missing anything?